# How to fit PDF height in UIWebView in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiwebview

I have a project that uses a UIWebView to display a single page PDF file.  I would like this content to fit by height (vertically).  The default is only to fit width (horizontally).  Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran against the same problem and couldn't find a way to do it with UIWebView. If you only want to display a single PDF-page, you can pretty much take the code from [Apple's ZoomingPDFViewer Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer).

I took the two classes PDFScrollView and TiledPDFView and with a little adjustment for my project, I  was easily able to use it to display a single PDF page.