# How to set initial zoom of PDF in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have an app that only supports portrait mode and a local PDF file in landscape orientation that I am loading into a fullscreen `UIWebView`. When I open the view, the pdf is displayed to full width, but I would like to display it full height (so that actually only a part of it is visible initially).

this is what I currently have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView.delegate = self;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plan" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

    [mapView loadRequest:request];
}
```

- `scalesPageToFit` is set to `YES` in `Storyboard`, as I would like users to be able to change the zoom level after initially loading the pdf.
- `contentMode` is set to `scaleToFill` (in `Storyboard`, too)

I've tried to play around with these values and also with setting `mapView.scrollView.zoomScale` programmatically, but no success so far.

How can I achieve that the PDF is loaded into the `UIWebView` **full height** instead of full width?

Comment: Check the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577663/how-to-fit-pdf-height-in-uiwebview-in-iphone-ipad

Comment: Thanks for your comment Anindya. From reading other questions on SO, I was afraid that I wouldn't be able to achieve this with a UIWebView - So I guess I'll have to read up on ZoomingPDFViewer as you suggest.